# While applying Material_Theme Error:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

Error_log:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                     Process: com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo, PID: 2611
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo/com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                         at com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   Application terminated.

Style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.hetal13.material_design_demo.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **do following changes** in your ***Style.xml***. (You can even try copy pasting this code snippet. Most Probably it should work.)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

All you need is **Theme.AppCompat theme** according to your logcat.

Hope this helps

Comment: But What to do if i want to add material design ui

Comment: **This is material theme only!** Just backward compatible. I guess you are just starting android dev so I would suggest you to have a look at official google docs for better understanding. **We should use Compatible themes so that pre-lollipop devices also get some material touch. **

Comment: I strongly recommend you to [read this link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html). Do consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: But My Emulator is too of Lollipop version

So why can't i use material design in this manner ??

Comment: **It got nothing to do with emulator**. In your java code are you extending your class like this ? `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ` Probably yes. So you can see you are extending from AppCompat and not using AppCompat theme.

Comment: @hetalshah Please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this , Sure it will solve your problem.

You can copy as it is...

```
    <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```